# Can't redirect trough a button to another blade

Tags: laravel, routes

In my example I have 4 buttons in the admin view and 2 buttons in my normal user's view! I'm struggling a bit trying to figure out how can I do the right routes etc.. to resolve my problem! I'm posting a few printscreens of my code and my blades.

The admin view:

[image]

web.php:

[image]

HomeController.php:

[image]

Comment: Don't upload your screenshots, Always try to copy your code as text and add it here, this way will help us to make a test

Answer (score 1):

First of all its always better to copy your code as text than uploading screenshots. This way we can copy and test it better.

Anyways. What the `url()` helper is doing is creating a full and absolute URL for a given path. In your case you're providing `users/index` which is not a path in your routes file.

Since you are already naming your routes you might want to do something like this:

`route('home')` instead of `url('users/index')`

If you still wan't to use or understand the url() helper. The correct usage for this route would be `url('/home')`

Comment: Sorry for the screenshots! The users/index is only an example! The one I'm working on is the consultaralmocos!

Comment: No worries. Did you try my solution? Any success with using the correct path or a named route?

Comment: I tried to do this:
'<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" onclick="window.location='{{ url('/consultaralmocos') }}'">
                            {{ __('Consultar Almoços') }}

I'm still getting the page not found error

Comment: Should I change anything at the web.php file?

Comment: Try `url('admin/consultaralmocos')` instead of `url('/consultaralmocos')`

Comment: Now it's giving me this error: 
InvalidArgumentException
View [consultaralmocos] not found.